# scrapy for loop responds everytime only the first element

Tags: python, loops, scrapy

I've tried to crawl a page with many "article" elements, but the loop returns everytime only the first element (as many as their are article elements).

```
for offer in response.xpath("//article"):
        product = Product() 
        product['kind'] = 'deal'
        product['portal'] = 'mydealz'
        product['link'] = offer.xpath("//a[@class='cept-dealBtn boxAlign-jc--all-c space--h-3 width--all-12 btn btn--mode-primary']/@href").get()
        product['merchant'] = offer.xpath("//div[@class='threadGrid']/div[@class='threadGrid-title']/a[@class='thread-title--list']/text()").get()
        #product['merchant'] = offer.xpath("//div[@class='threadGrid']/div[@class='threadGrid-title js-contextual-message-placeholder']/div[@class='overflow--fade']/a[@class='cept-merchant-link text--color-greyShade size--all-s']/span[@class='cept-merchant-link-term overflow--wrap-off']/span[@class='text--b text--color-brandPrimary cept-merchant-name']/text()").get()
        product['offer'] = offer.xpath("//div[@class='threadGrid']/div[@class='threadGrid-title js-contextual-message-placeholder']/strong[@class='thread-title']/a[@class='cept-tt thread-link linkPlain thread-title--list']/text()").get()
        #product['offer'] = offer.xpath("//div[@class='threadGrid']/div[@class='threadGrid-title js-contextual-message-placeholder']/strong[@class='thread-title']/a[@class='cept-tt thread-link linkPlain thread-title--list']/text()").get()
        product['crawlingdate'] = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())
        yield product
```

Comment: Your xpath is wrong. '//' means from the doc root. You maybe want './'

Comment: Please provide the link to be scraped, we need to test it locally in order to help you.

Comment: The page is: https://www.mydealz.de/gruppe/telefon-internet

Comment: @pguardiario Your solution works! Thanks!